# Nginx redirect being ignored

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to create a redirect for all URLs on a domain that contains /comfy/ to another domain, but keeping the rest of the request.

For example
https://www.example.org/system/comfy/cms/files/files/000/002/012/profile/AdobeStock_194204879.jpeg

to

https://www2.example.org/system/comfy/cms/files/files/000/002/012/profile/AdobeStock_194204879.jpeg

In nginx in the server block for example.org I have

```
location ~ ^/comfy/(.*) {
return 301 $scheme://www2.example.org/$request_uri;
```

}

but i'm still getting a 404, with the original domain, ie it's still accessing

```
https://www.example.org/system/comfy/cms/files/files/000/002/012/profile/AdobeStock_194204879.jpeg
```

I have also tried

```
rewrite ^(/comfy/)(.*)$ http://www2.example.org/$2 permanent;
```

and

```
rewrite ^/comfy/(.*) http://www2.example.org/$1 break;
```

but these are failing too.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I needed to do

```
location ~ ^/system/comfy/cms/(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://www2.example.org/$request_uri;
}
```